# Is it possible to build a xero uk/GB bank Account without a bank account number of the format xxxxxx-xxxxxxxx?

Tags: xero-api

Is it possible to build a xero uk/GB bank Account without a bank account number of the format xxxxxx-xxxxxxxx? I'm trying to attach a balance in our product to a xero bank account but I don't have a uk style bank number. Is there a way to create a bank account that doesn't require a bank account number in that format (apart from Paypal and credit card bank accounts)? I haven't noticed this requirement with the US variant of Xero.

Comment: The restriction for creating UK bank acounts via the API will just make sure you have at least 6 digits (despite the validation error returned). You can even just pad it with zeroes to make to work. What format is the number you're trying to use?

Comment: Ideally we'd be using our own internal ID format - so we can figure out which of our internal account balances match the one we're creating in Xero. But a bunch of zeros will work too. We'll have to match on name instead.